# A cleaner/better way to write jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been editing some jQuery and it seems just adding on IF statements to the function. What the function does or what the if statements do is not really that important. I am just wondering if there is a better/cleaner way to write the following:

```
scrollToTop: function() {
    var offset = 160;
    var duration = 500;
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
      if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
        jQuery('#top-link-block').fadeIn(duration);
      } else {
        jQuery('#top-link-block').fadeOut(duration);
      }
      if (jQuery('#top-link-block').offset().top + jQuery('#top-link-block').height() >= jQuery('#footer-wrapper').offset().top - 10)
        jQuery('#top-link-block').css('position', 'absolute');
      if (jQuery(document).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight < jQuery('#footer-wrapper').offset().top)
        jQuery('#top-link-block').css('position', 'fixed');
      if (jQuery('#fixed-toolbar-menu')[0]) {
        jQuery('#top-link-block').css({
          bottom: 150
        });
      }
    });
```

Comment: What it does "IS" very important, it helps decide "the best way" to code a given function.

Comment: Also, this kind of question is a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What problem (if any) are you having with this code? just hard to read? or is it not performing as expected or is jumpy/jittery. It will function a bit oddly if you scroll quickly between 150 and 170 repeatedly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for one continuously querying for the same DOM objects is not only repetitive, but costly. You should always capture your query results with a variable. Doing this alone, will clean up your code:

```
 var $tlb = jQuery('#top-link-block');
```

NOTE: I suggest prefixing your JQuery result variable with a $ to remind you that it is a JQuery wrapper object and not a traditional DOM object.

Now, you can just use this variable over and over:

```
 if ($tlb.offset...)...
```

In addition, you are using this value:

```
 jQuery('#footer-wrapper').offset().top
```

more than once, so I'd save that value in a variable as well:

```
 var $footWrapOffsetTop = jQuery('#footer-wrapper').offset().top;
```

And then you can use that where needed without having to query the object and extract the offset.top value repeatedly.

Also, this:

```
 jQuery(window)
```

is wasteful because since you are not capturing the result of the query and only using the query so that you can attach an event handler to window. Using JQuery to get a reference to the global window object does nothing more than perform a lookup on an object that is always available. Just use:

```
 window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){...});
```

The only benefit for querying for window would be to take advantage of JQuery's wrapped-set functions, but you aren't doing that here.

Here's the cleaned up version (using best-practices):

```
    scrollToTop: function () {

      var offset = 160;
      var duration = 500;

      // Result is JQuery wrapped-set object:
      var $tlb = jQuery('#top-link-block');

      // Result is top value:
      var footWrapOffsetTop = $('#footer-wrapper').offset().top;

      window.addEventListener('scroll', (function() {

        // Don't take advantage of optional curly braces with blocks
        // of only one statement. It can lead to bugs.
        if (window.scrollTop() > offset){
            $tlb.fadeIn(duration) : $tlb.fadeOut(duration);
        }

        if ($tlb.offset().top + $tlb.height() >= footWrapOffsetTop - 10) {
            $tlb.css('position', 'absolute');
        }

        if ($(document).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight < footWrapOffsetTop){
            $tlb.css('position', 'fixed');
        }

        if ($('#fixed-toolbar-menu')[0]){
            $tlb.css({ bottom: 150 });
        }
      });
```

Comment: Why the down vote? This directly addresses the question and improves performance.